# Keeping track of modifications in Power BI data

Tags: variables, powerbi, storage, powerbi-desktop

Let's say I have a list of the members of a team, and I keep track of their status (active/inactive, or present/absent, for instance). My file contains an id for each member, a column "updated at timestamp" as well as a column giving their current status. The list is updated daily, so some member's status can change from one day to the next.

What I would like to do is get the number of days the status was on "active/present" during a month (or a percentage of "active" during the month).

The problem being that the data is not stored : when there is an update, the column "status" changes but there is no history on whether it was on active/present or inactive/absent the previous day.

Could someone help me find a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need a transactional database/dataset to do what you ask. If you don't save each historic change you can never know what it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

For the situation you mentioned, you can use a RDBMS systems. I am writing for SQL Server, probably you would use the "Temporal Table" for historical information.